# pointer-events: none does not work on material-ui textField input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, pointer-events

I've got a `material-ui textField input`, and I'm setting the css on it to `pointer-events: none`, but this does not prevent the user from entering text in the input.

I know I can add a `disabled={true}` flag but if I can do this with `CSS` it would be much simpler - instead of adding more logic, checking for props etc - I can just disable it based on a parent class.

**How do you use pointer-events: none with a materialUI textField input?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `disabled` attribute on inputs is the correct method of disabling the input. `pointer-events: none` is typically used on SVG images to suppress click events.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    pointerEvents: "none"
  }
});
```

and then in text field

```
<TextField
className={classes.textField} />
```

that way you don't have to override disabled css.